# Limit approaching a pole of $\phi(s)=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} - \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^s(p^s -1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

If:
$$\phi(s) = -\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} - \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^s(p^s -1)},$$

where $\zeta(s)$ is the riemann zeta function, why is:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon\phi(1+\epsilon) = 1\quad ?$$

I feel it in the intuitive sense, but I'm unable to prove it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider only the first part of $\phi(s)$ that we will note $f(s):=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ (the remaining part is bounded for $s$ near $1$) then from the [Stieltjes expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) :
$$\zeta(z)=\frac 1{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\gamma_n\;(z-1)^n$$
we get $\ \zeta(1+\epsilon)\sim \frac 1{\epsilon}$ and $\ \zeta(1+\epsilon)'\sim -\frac 1{\epsilon^2}$ so that :
$$-\epsilon\frac{\zeta(1+\epsilon)'}{\zeta(1+\epsilon)}\sim 1$$

Comment: can I say instead that because i know that $\psi(s) = \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1}$ is holomporphic (then bounded) for $\Re(s) > 0$, then $\zeta(s) = \psi(s) + \frac{1}{s-1}$ and so $\zeta(1 + \epsilon) = someting limited + ∼\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ etc..?

Comment: @Benzio: Yes when you remove the simple pole at $1$ (of residue $1$) you get a function holomorphic everywhere in the complex plane and bounded in a disk around $1$.

Comment: @Benzio: You may too use the integral $\ \displaystyle\zeta(s)=\frac s{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u^{1+s}}\,du\ $ to deduce (since $\frac s{s-1}=\frac 1{s-1}+1$) that $\zeta$ admits a pole of order $1$ at $s=1$ and of residue $1$ : this is the Dirichlet theorem that allows to write the Stieljes expansion.

Comment: thank you for your help Raymond :-)

Comment: You are welcome @Benzio !